# flickr.photos.search

Tags: php, flickr

I would like to ask for help. I got this homework to create a class in PHP with search method which returns 50 pictures from Flickr, but without use of official PHP Flickr libraries... Anyway with help of google I wrote following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        class Flickr { 
            private $apiKey = 'aba429532a6606f2ee35e3f47a300716';
            public function search($query = null) { 
                $search = 'http://flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=' . $this->apiKey . '&text=' . urlencode($query) . '&per_page=50&format=php_serial'; 
                $result = file_get_contents($search);
                $result = unserialize($result);
                return $result;
            }
        }
        ?>
        <form action="index.php" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="text1" /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Send" /><br />
        </form>
        <?php
        if(isset($_GET["submit1"])) {
            $Flickr = new Flickr; 
            $data = $Flickr->search($_GET["text1"]); 
            foreach($data['photos']['photo'] as $photo) {
                echo '<img src="http://farm' . $photo["farm"] . '.static.flickr.com/' . $photo["server"] . '/' . $photo["id"] . '_' . $photo["secret"] . '.jpg">'; 
            }
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

That code does what I need, but I am not sure whether I can use flickr.photos.search, so I was wondering if there is a way to avoid using flickr.photos.search.

Comment: Why shouldn't you be allowed to use the search-method? Calling the method server-side has got nothing to do with the PHP flickr libraries (also, i do not think you'll get around doing it the way you are already doing it). Another possibility would be using the feeds, but that's not as flexible as the API: http://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just request `http://www.flickr.com/search/?q={work_by_witch_you_search}&z=m` pictures from here with curl and just parse received page. Then you definitely wount use anything even close to Flickr API.